# Facebook share dialog close on cancel instead of redirecting?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using this URL :

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=xxx&display=popup&href=' . urlencode($url) . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($url)
```

I use window.open to open this in a popup window.

Ideally when I click on cancel I simply want the popup window to close.. but only when I know for sure that it's a popup window. So the behavior should be different for mobile browsers, I presume?

How can I do this?

Comment: Redirect to a page that does `window.close()`.

Comment: @ceejaoyz please add this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is typically making the `redirect_uri` go to a page on your server that does a simple JavaScript `window.close()`.

Mobile devices shouldn't be a problem - they open in an new window instead of a popup and `window.close()` works in the same way. Consider including text saying something like "You may now close this window" in case the user doesn't have JS enabled or `window.close()` doesn't have permissions for an unusual reason.